# urllib.urlopen() on variables that are assigned a string values wont work?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, urllib

Im writing some code to parse an XML file. Im just wondering if someone could explain why this isn't working.  If I put `link` itself into `urllib.urlopen()`, it does not seem to make it to that url. However, when I put `"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max- results=50&time=today"` inside `urllib.urlopen()`, it works. Does it need to be a string and not a variable or is there a way around it?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Uel(object):
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.content_data = []  
        self.num_likes = []
        self.num_dislikes = []
        self.favoritecount = []
        self.view_count = []
        self.link = link
        self.web_obj = urllib.urlopen(link)
        self.file = open('youtubequery.txt', 'w+')
        self.file.write(str(self.web_obj))
        for i in self.web_obj:
            self.file.write(i)
        with open("youtubequery.txt", "r") as myfile:
            self.file_2=myfile.read()
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.file_2)

        for link in self.soup.find_all("content"):
            self.content_data.append(str(link.get("src")))

        for stat in self.soup.find_all("yt:statistics"):
            self.favoritecount.append(str(stat.get("favoritecount")))

        for views in self.soup.find_all("yt:statistics"):
            self.view_count.append(str(views.get("viewcount")))

        for numlikes in self.soup.find_all("yt:rating"):
            self.num_likes.append(str(numlikes.get("numlikes")))

        for numdislikes in self.soup.find_all("yt:rating"):
            self.num_dislikes.append(str(numdislikes.get("numdislikes")))


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content_data),str(self.num_likes), str(self.num_dislikes)

link = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max- results=50&time=5"
data = Uel(link)
print data.__str__()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've presented, you are using this url:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max- results=50&time=5
```

a request to which produces:

```
Invalid value for time parameter: 5
```

But, in the question itself, you've mentioned the following URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max- results=50&time=today
```

which has `time=today`. The code with this URL works for me.